# PHP display array values

Tags: php, arrays, display

So, I'm new with PHP and I'm trying to display ONLY the values of an array.
The methods like print_r, var_dump, etc don't work for this because I only want the values of the array.

My array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 1 La Defense - Chateau de Vincennes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 2 Porte Dauphine - Nation
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 3 Pont de Levallois Becon - Gallieni
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 3bis Gambetta - Porte des Lilas
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 4 Porte de Clignancourt - Mairie de Montrouge
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 5 Bobigny Pablo Picasso - Place d�Italie
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 6 Charles de Gaulle Etoile - Nation
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 7 Louis Leblanc - Pre Saint Gervais
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 8 Balard - Pointe du Lac
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 9 Pont de S�vres - Mairie de Montreuil
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 10 Boulogne Pont de Saint Cloud - Gare d�Austerlitz
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 11 Chatelet - Mairie des Lilas
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 12 Front Populaire - Mairie d�Issy
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [linea] => 13 Gare Saint Lazare - Olympiades
        )

)
```

I want to display the content of the array like this:

```
["1 La Defense - Chateau de Vincennes", "2 Porte Dauphine - Nation", ...]
```

I don't know if this is possible, as I said before I'm new on PHP and don't know if it's possible, thanks for your for your help!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
<?php
$data = [
    ['linea' => '1 La Defense - Chateau de Vincennes'],
    ['linea' => '2 Porte Dauphine - Nation'],
    ['linea' => '3 Pont de Levallois Becon - Gallieni'],
    ['linea' => '3bis Gambetta - Porte des Lilas'],
    ['linea' => '4 Porte de Clignancourt - Mairie de Montrouge'],
    ['linea' => '5 Bobigny Pablo Picasso - Place d�Italie'],
    ['linea' => '6 Charles de Gaulle Etoile - Nation'],
    ['linea' => '7 Louis Leblanc - Pre Saint Gervais'],
    ['linea' => '8 Balard - Pointe du Lac'],
    ['linea' => '9 Pont de S�vres - Mairie de Montreuil'],
    ['linea' => '10 Boulogne Pont de Saint Cloud - Gare d�Austerlitz'],
    ['linea' => '11 Chatelet - Mairie des Lilas'],
    ['linea' => '12 Front Populaire - Mairie d�Issy'],
    ['linea' => '13 Gare Saint Lazare - Olympiades']
];

$data = array_column($data, 'linea');
print_r($data);
```

https://3v4l.org/IhSHD

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 La Defense - Chateau de Vincennes
    [1] => 2 Porte Dauphine - Nation
    [2] => 3 Pont de Levallois Becon - Gallieni
    [3] => 3bis Gambetta - Porte des Lilas
    [4] => 4 Porte de Clignancourt - Mairie de Montrouge
    [5] => 5 Bobigny Pablo Picasso - Place d�Italie
    [6] => 6 Charles de Gaulle Etoile - Nation
    [7] => 7 Louis Leblanc - Pre Saint Gervais
    [8] => 8 Balard - Pointe du Lac
    [9] => 9 Pont de S�vres - Mairie de Montreuil
    [10] => 10 Boulogne Pont de Saint Cloud - Gare d�Austerlitz
    [11] => 11 Chatelet - Mairie des Lilas
    [12] => 12 Front Populaire - Mairie d�Issy
    [13] => 13 Gare Saint Lazare - Olympiades
)
```

> I want to display the content of the array like this:

```
["1 La Defense - Chateau de Vincennes", "2 Porte Dauphine - Nation", ...]
```

Your want [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for that:

`echo json_encode($data);`

https://3v4l.org/Pue0V

**Result:**

```
["1 La Defense - Chateau de Vincennes","2 Porte Dauphine - Nation","3 Pont de Levallois Becon - Gallieni","3bis Gambetta - Porte des Lilas","4 Porte de Clignancourt - Mairie de Montrouge","5 Bobigny Pablo Picasso - Place d\ufffdItalie","6 Charles de Gaulle Etoile - Nation","7 Louis Leblanc - Pre Saint Gervais","8 Balard - Pointe du Lac","9 Pont de S\ufffdvres - Mairie de Montreuil","10 Boulogne Pont de Saint Cloud - Gare d\ufffdAusterlitz","11 Chatelet - Mairie des Lilas","12 Front Populaire - Mairie d\ufffdIssy","13 Gare Saint Lazare - Olympiades"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, I have to use this line:                                         $utfEncodedArray = $array_map("utf8_encode", $data);                         before the method json_encode() because if I don't do it then json_encode($data) returned false, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arrays   = $your_array_here;
$output  = '';

foreach ( $arrays as $value ) {
    $output .= ' " '.  implode( ",",  $value ) .' ", ';
}

echo '[' . rtrim( $outout, ", " ) . ']’;
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.